# How to remove old ArrayList items while simultaneously accessing new ones

Tags: arraylist, processing

I have a program that reads in a text file, adds certain objects to an ArrayList, then accesses them later in order to display the objects. However, the file is very big (8.5 million lines) and thus so is the ArrayList (which is what I assume causes my program to hang as soon as I run it.)

I would like to remove the older items in the ArrayList while I am accessing newer ones, so that I can keep the ArrayList small in size. It doesn't seem to be working with my current code- is this the right way to remove older items in an ArrayList?

Here is the relevant code:

```java
void drawPoints() {
  for (int i = 0; i < places.size(); i++) {
    places.get(i).placeCoordinate();
    places.get(i).fadeCoordinate();
      if (i >= 1) {
        places.remove(i - 1);
      }
   }
}
```

Some notes:

- `places` is the ArrayList that at this point should be filled with objects from the file.
- The function `drawPoints()` is called in the main `draw()` loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a size you want to enforce, let's say `10`, then you can simply do a check whenever you add something to the `ArrayList`:

```java
ArrayList<Thing> list = new ArrayList<Thing>();

list.add(thing);

if(list.size() == 10){
   list.remove(0); //removes the oldest thing
}
```

Or if you really want to remove stuff while you're looping over the `ArrayList`, you could simply loop backwards so the shifting of indexes doesn't interfere with the loop variable:

```java
  for (int i = places.size()-1; i >= 0; i--) {
    places.get(i).placeCoordinate();
    places.get(i).fadeCoordinate();
      if (i >= 1) {
        places.remove(i - 1);
      }
   }
```

Or you could use an `Iterator`:

```java
ArrayList<Thing> list = new ArrayList<Thing>();

//create your Iterator
Iterator<Thing> iterator = list.iterator();

//loop over every Thing in the ArrayList
while(iterator.hasNext()){
  Thing thing = iterator.next();

  thing.doSomething();

  if(thing.shouldBeRemoved()){
    //Iterator allows you to remove stuff without messing up your loop
    iterator.remove();
  }
}
```